# How to map one vim command to execute bash commands based on OS?

Tags: bash, vim

In short, can single bash commands in the terminal contain conditionals? If so, how?

I have in my vimrc (shared across systems) the following command to open my current LaTeX document in .pdf form:
`map ,v :!gnome-open %<.pdf <CR> <CR>`

My question is, what is the best way to have ,v execute simply "open %<.pdf" when I'm at home on my OS X machine? Here is my pseudo-code guess:

`... if [$OSTYPE == "darwin*"] then open %<.pdf else gnome-open %<.pdf ...`

This is executed as a single BASH command. Are such conditionals possible? If so, could someone help me with the syntax? If not, can this be done via conditionals in the vimrc file?

Comment: If you want to use a single script across all OSes, I follow Jander's suggestion since it seems like you're comfortable enough with bash.  Write a bash script that's checks $OSTYPE, uname, which/whereis/type, or whatever is appropriate and call the script from vim using your keybinding.

Comment: @Jander and @penguin359: both of your answers have taught me what I need to know to do this and more. I'm very thankful!

Answer (score 6):

An alternate would be to just generate the map keybinding correctly for the OS.  For example:

```
if executable("cmd.exe")
    map ,v :!cmd.exe /C start "" "%<.pdf"<CR><CR>
elseif $OSTYPE =~ "darwin.*"
    map ,v :!open '%<.pdf'<CR><CR>
elseif executable("gnome-open")
    map ,v :!gnome-open '%<.pdf'<CR><CR>
endif
```

This was tested and appears to work, but as my Vim script is a little shaky and I might have missed some details like proper quoting, I'd probably go more with Jander's approach and just use a shell wrapper which I am far superior in writing.

```
map ,v :!open.sh '%<.pdf'<CR><CR>
```

And in `~/bin/open.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if echo "$OSTYPE" | grep "^darwin" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    open "$@" &
elif type gnome-open &>/dev/null; then
    gnome-open "$@" &
fi
```

Comment: Nice.  I missed the idea of doing the OS detection from within the shellscript.  One minor point -- I think you mean "gnome-open" instead of "gnome-terminal".

Comment: @Jander yea, I was thinking there was something funny about what I wrote.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, if I were going to do this, I'd create a `~/bin/open.sh` script with whatever "open" command is correct for the OS, and make sure `~/bin` is in my path on all my machines.  It scales better that way in case I want to add a Windows+Cygwin box, for example.  The downside is that you need to have a different script for each type of machine, although the scripts are dead simple so it's really not too bad.

So, in ~/bin/open.sh on the Mac:

```
#!/bin/sh
open "$@"
```

And in ~/bin/open.sh on Linux:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-open "$@"
```

And in vimrc:

```
map ,v :!open.sh %<.pdf<CR><CR>
```

---

...Alternately, if you prefer to have everything on the `:!` line, then you can use a semicolon wherever you would normally use a newline in a shell script.  To adapt your example:

```
... if [ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin10.0" ]; then open %<.pdf; else gnome-open %<.pdf; fi
```